# How to integrate by reduction method

Tags: integration

How to evaluate the integrals of

(a) $(\ln(x))^n$

(b) $x^ne^{ax}$ where $a$ is a constant

By reduction formula

Answer (score 1):

- $$\int(\ln(x))^ndx=x(\ln(x))^n-\int xd((\ln(x))^n)=x(\ln(x))^n-\int x\left(\dfrac{n(\ln(x))^{n-1}}{x}\right)dx\\
  \implies \int(\ln(x))^ndx=x(\ln(x))^n-\int {n(\ln(x))^{n-1}}dx$$
- $$\int x^ne^{ax}dx=\dfrac{1}{a}\int x^nd(e^{ax})=\dfrac{1}{a}e^{ax}x^n-\dfrac{1}{a}\int e^{ax}(nx^{n-1})dx$$

Answer (score 0):

For the first question define $I_{n}=\int(\ln(x))^{n}dx$ then by integrating by parts we have:

$$I_{n}=x(\ln(x))^{n}-n\int(\ln(x))^{n-1}dx=x(\ln(x))^{n}-nI_{n-1}$$

For (b) we define $I_{n}=\int x^{n}e^{ax}dx$ then by integrating by parts we have:

$$I_{n}=\frac{1}{a}x^{n}e^{ax}-\frac{n}{a}\int x^{n-1}e^{ax}dx=\frac{1}{a}x^{n}e^{ax}-\frac{n}{a}I_{n-1}$$

Comment: I thought I should leave it to you to practice the same technique on (b) but I'll add the answer for (b).